# weird behavior Expression<Func> in EfCore HasQueryFilter method v2.2 (Refactoring problem)

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.2

I have a QueryFilter in my AppDbContext EfCore 2.2 :

```
builder.Entity<MessageReceiver> ().HasQueryFilter (
    (q) => (q.ReciverId == _uai.LoggedInUserId) || 
           (q.Message.SenderId == _uai.LoggedInUserId));
```

this code is working fine because i injected a custom service (`_uai`) to check logged-in user information into my AppDbContext.

```
   public class AppDbContext : DbContext {
      private readonly IUserAccessInfoService _uai;

      public AppDbContext (DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options, IUserAccessInfoService userAccessInfo) : base (options) {
         _uai = userAccessInfo;
      }
```

but i can not refactor this code and move entire expression to my service! 
after refactoring this code to '_uai' service i'm using that like :

```
builder.Entity<MessageReceiver> ().HasQueryFilter (_uai.GetMessageQueryFilter ());
```

and in my 'uai' service i refactored expression :

```
// UserAccessInfoService ....

public Expression<Func<MessageReceiver, bool>> GetMessageQueryFilter () {
         return (q) =>
            (q.ReciverId == LoggedInUserId) || 
            (q.Message.SenderId == LoggedInUserId);
      }

// this way loggedInUser is null in runtime
```

does Have expressions some inline cache capabilities ? the problem is EFCore not using injected service values when i refactored this code and LoggedInUserId is null after refactoring.
i think there is some kind of caching that efcore is using for its expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expressions used in global query filters are special. In particular, they are evaluated just once *except* the parts which come from field, property or method of the `DbContext` (as in your original code).

This is partially explained in EF Core [Global Query Fiters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) documentation example:

> **Tip**
>
> Note the use of a DbContext instance level field: `_tenantId` used to set the current tenant. Model-level filters will use the value from the correct context instance (that is, the instance that is executing the query).

I would like they to be more explicit and explicitly explain that behavior in the documentation rather than as a tip to an example, because this actually is **the only way** to get dynamically evaluated filter.

With that being said, keep the original code as is, or use different way of refactoring in case you need this in several places - interface/base class/ `EF.Property` or manual expression composition to bind the `ReceiverId` and `SenderId` expressions, but still compare them to `this._uai.LoggedInUserId`.

Comment: i can't see a different way unfortunately ... I can not use anything if I want to keep my query filters and reuse the code.

Comment: about your reply to others having the same problem, I should say, just fields and properties are working in Global query filters, not methods (even in DbContext class).